# Make a pie chart with tymeleaf highcharts spring mvc java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, highcharts

I want to create a pie chart with a dynamic data in highcharts

i really need your help

i wanna make a pie chart that counts the gender

here is my code

im really stuck there

..........................................................................

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/piechart")
        public ResponseEntity<?> getAll(Model model) {
        List<user> list =  userRepository.allusers();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(list,HttpStatus.OK);
    
    }
```

Repository :

```
 @Query(value=" SELECT *,count(*) AS count_gender FROM user GROUP BY gender", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> allusers();
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'piechart',
        dataType:'json',
        
        success: function(result){
            var series=[];
            var data= [];
        
            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                var object={};
                object.name=result[i].gender;
                object.y=result[i];
                data.push(object);
            }
            var seriesObject={
                    name:'percentage',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: data
            }
            series.push(seriesObject);
            drewPiechart(series);
        }
    })
    function drewPiechart(series){
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
        });
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
                
            },
            title: {
              
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function(){
                    return 'y value: '+this.y+'<br/>is '+this.percentage+'% of total ('+this.total+')';
                }
            },
            accessibility: {
                point: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                    },
            showInLegend: true
                }
            },
           
            series: series
         });
    }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

here is my result:

it shows nothing bcz i didnt know how to get the count result of the query on the yaxis

[image: it shows nothing]

Comment: 1. How your `series` array looks like? 2. Notice that pie series supports only one series config with multiple points - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n3Lx9rwc/ API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/pie-chart

Comment: my series looks like the example u gave but it gives wrong numbers

Comment: please reproduce your issue with the sample data that you are receiving